# SOQL query to show contacts and accounts located within a state that have a certain custom object relationship

Tags: soql

I'm trying to create an SOQL query with a subquery to show contacts and accounts located within a state that have a certain custom object relationship:

**Here is my code:**

```
    public with sharing class AccountsinPlacesExt {
    @AuraEnabled

        public Place__c place { get; private set; }
        public List<Account> inPlaceAccounts { get; private set; }
        public AccountsinPlacesExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
        {
            // add the Place__c field that tells you which state
            List<String> neededFields = new List<String> { 'City__c','State_Code__c' };
            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(neededFields);
            place = (Place__c)controller.getRecord();

           if (place.City__c != null) {
           // search for city and state match
                inPlaceAccounts = [ 
                    SELECT Id,Name,Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__r,(SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Our_Role_Count__c > 0 AND BillingCity = :place.City__c AND BillingState = :place.State_Code__c AND Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__c WHERE Our_Role__r.Name != 'Outreach')
                ];
           } else {
           //search for only state match
                inPlaceAccounts = [
    SELECT Id,Name,Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__r,(SELECT Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Our_Role_Count__c > 0 AND BillingState = :place.State_Code__c AND Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__c WHERE Our_Role__r.Name != 'Outreach')
               ];
           }
           // end else
        }

    }
```

**Now I'm still seeing:**

I tried but it isn't working now. even in the dev console I'm seeing an error: `SELECT Id,Name,Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__r` ^

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:16 No such column
>   'Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__r' on entity 'Account'. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Have you tried to use just `Account__c` instead of `Account__r.Id`? Also in your inner query you can just query the account's Ids. The other values are not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to filter results based on a separate query, that is called a [Left Inner Join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join).

```
SELECT Name FROM Position_c WHERE Id IN
(SELECT Position__c FROM Job_Application__c)
```

When you try to pull in parent fields in a `SELECT` clause, it's called a [Right Outer Join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join).

```
SELECT Name, Position__r.Department__c FROM Job_Application__c
```

You cannot combine these types of join. But you're needlessly complicating things, since `SomeLookup__r.Id` is always the same value as `SomeLookup__c`. So in this case, just use that. You also have to remove all other fields, the only field you are allowed to have in a `Left Inner Join` query is the field you are filtering on. So change your join to:

```
(SELECT Account__c FROM Our_Role_Service_Affiliation_for_Account__c WHERE Our_Role__r.Name != 'Outreach')
```

Any fields you want to retrieve from the queried records must be in the *top-level* `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT Name, OtherFieldsToRetrieve__c FROM Account
```

Comment: Left, right, outer, inner, I still can never remember which is which. I just know I want to pull in lookup, detail records, or filter based on a query lol.

Comment: I updated my question as I now am getting a new error...

Comment: @soxdave You need to put the fields in your top-level select clause...

Comment: the other fields are related to another object.. and i want to pull records related to those. is that not possible? it works as written in the developer console but when i put it in the apex page it doesn't work as i'm not calling it from the account page but rather from a custom object called Places.